# How to remove unicode special characters from a string (URL) using regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var url="�http://www.theaustralian.com.au/australian-it/it-business/eugene-kaspersky-queries-breach-rules/story-e6frganx-1226656443211�"
```

I want to remove the Unicode special character at the beginning and end of the URL using JavaScript regular expression.

Comment: `url = url.replace(/\uFFFD/g, '')`? To get the correct hex code, you can always use [r12a >> apps >> Unicode code converter](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/).

Comment: What about `var res = url.substring(1, url.length-1);` ? ;)

Comment: What is an "unicode special character"?

Comment: Or just: `url = url.slice(1, -1)`

Comment: It doesn't make sense for them to be there in the first place. You should check where you get your string and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
/^[^\w]+|[^\w]+$/mg
```

```js
var url="�http://www.theaustralian.com.au/australian-it/it-business/eugene-kaspersky-queries-breach-rules/story-e6frganx-1226656443211�";
document.write(url.replace(/^[^\w]+|[^\w]+$/mg, ""));
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro for the solution!